# Flexslider adding white space above and below slides

Tags: flexslider

Could anyone tell me why this might be? I'm a novice, but I don't see anything in flexslider.css that could have added this space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Seems to be mainly due to the whitespace when copied from the FlexSlider site's example html.

The example is formatted like this:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you reformat it like this...

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="slide1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

... most of the unwanted space disappears.

By default there is also a 4px border on the .flexslider div, and I also had one more line of unwanted whitespace which I removed with a negative top margin equal to my default line height:

```
.flexslider {
    border: 0 !important;
    margin-top: -1.4em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your slider contains image elements, you might need to set your images to `display:block`. Also, if you could provide an example, it would be easier to diagnose.